# Get the element which triggered the event in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

How could I get the element which triggered the event in **d3.js**?

For example, I can have code like this.

```
const element = d3.select("#elementId");
element.on("mousedown", function(){element.text("element was clicked");});
```

Now I would like to avoid using the *element* in `function(){element.text("element was clicked");}` directly.

I am expecting to get something like `function(){getElementFromContextSomehow.text("element was clicked");}` where **getElementFromContextSomehow** === **element** is true.

I remember seeing something like this but I forgot. Could someone help me to figure this out, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your event handler, `this` should be the DOM element that triggered the event.

Alternatively, you can access the original DOM event inside the event handler via `d3.event` property, and get the DOM element from there.

Comment: Should I use `d3.select(this)` to get the `element` above?

Comment: No need for that, simply use ‘this’ to get access to the DOM element.